# Problem with woocommerce product search and 403 error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-403

I am at a loss.
I have a website where only registered customers are allowed to see prices and order products. While Guest visitors are allowed to browse the products. It has been working smoothly for a long time. But recently Using WooCommerce Product Search I get search results when logged in, but not as a guest user ?

T make things really weird, it works on mobile, both as logged and as guest user. So the problem is only on desktop browsers....

The Console throws this error when I am NOT logged into my site:

```
jquery.min.js:2     POST https://******.**/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?title=1&excerpt=1&content=1&categories=1&attributes=1&tags=1&sku=1&product_thumbnails=1 403
```

Now 403 means I have not the right permission?

Any ideas ?
There is no Error logs in WP, I only see the error in the console.

I have tried to deactivate plugins that may interfere, I have tried to kill the cache, anything I can think of, but no, nope, nada.
I have tried disabling the plugin that controls access to prices and cart
I have tried resetting cache
I have checked user roles
I have checked all the settings in WooCommerce
I even tried this hack:

```
    function wpb_change_search_url() {
if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) && ($_GET['post_type'] != 'product') ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url( "/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) . 
   "&post_type=product" );
    exit();
}   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

But no, nothing, nada. If I had any hair on my head it would've been pulled out by now.
I will be very greatful for any tips, and hints or fixes at all